# Static Resource in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, bulk

I have written the static resource inside the for loop of sending the email using apex trigger,For that i have declared the static resource manually and accessed I need to bulkify and we have to declare the static resource outside the for loop using map and list and then i have to access inside the for loop,I am little bit struggling

```
for (attachment attachmentlst1 : attachmentlst )
{
    if(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).Subtype__c =='Offer' || Market=='FR')
    {
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-FR'); 
        ResourceName = 'TC_for_France';
        TCname = 'CONDITIONS_GENERALES_DEVENTE.pdf';
    }
    if(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).Subtype__c =='ASP' || Market=='IT')
    {
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-IT');
        ResourceName = 'TC_for_Italy';
        TCname = 'Condizioni_generali_di_vendita.pdf';
    }
    User currentUser = [Select Id, Phone,name from User where Id =:System.UserInfo.getUserId()];
    mail.setToAddresses(Toaddress);
    mail.setCcAddresses(CCaddress);
    mail.setSubject(Orderid);
    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
    efa.setFileName(attachmentlst1.Name);
    efa.setBody(attachmentlst1.Body);
    fileAttachments.add(efa);
    StaticResource TC = [select body from StaticResource where Name=:ResourceName];
    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
    efa1.setFileName(TCname);
    efa1.setBody(TC.Body);
    fileAttachments.add(efa1);
    mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
}
```

Comment: We're apparently missing some code. ResourceName is not defined in this code block. Can you please share the entire trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're having problems with bulkification. This comes in two general forms: combining queries for efficiency, and combining expensive operations, like DML and sendEmail, into bulk operations.

So, you should combine your email sends into a single list, and combine your static resource queries into a single query. I'd start off with this:

```
Map<String, Blob> resources = new Map<String, Blob>();
for(StaticResource resource:[SELECT Name, Body FROM StaticResource 
                             WHERE Name IN ('TC_for_France','TC_for_Italy')]) {
    resources.put(resource.Name, resource.Body);
}
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
for(Attachment attachmentlst1: attachmentlst) {
    // ... omitted ...
    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
    efa1.setFileName(TCname);
    efa1.setBody(resources.get(resourceName));
    // ... omitted ...
    messages.add(mail);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

Comment: for conditon is there for france one resource and italy another resource how to check condition? @sfdcfox

Comment: @user36188 Most of your code is just fine. This answer illustrates the changes you need to make for bulkification. I've omitted the if statements and other non-essential code to focus on the question's premise and brevity. Please study this code, adjust your existing code with the new pieces, and try it out.

Comment: @user36188 Yes, they are necessary--again, I've omitted them for brevity.

Comment: @user36188 Something like this: `AccountMap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).AccountId).Name`